# Trying to filter by lt and gt

Tags: django

I have a gps point and I want to find the objects that contain that point.

```
latitude = request.POST['latitude']
longitude = request.POST['longitude']

# finds the objects where the user coordinate are in the min/max bounding box 
filterargs = {  'object_id' : object_id, 
                'max_latitude__gt'  : latitude, 
                'min_latitude__lt'  : latitude, 
                'max_longitude__gt' : longitude, 
                'min_longitude__lt' : longitude     }

objects = ObjectModel.objects.filter(**filterargs)
```

It works if I do this:

```
filterargs = {  'object_id' : object_id, 
                'max_latitude__gt'  : latitude }
```

But it doesn't like all the arguments

I think it is suppose to say:

find the object who's max latitude is greater than the users latitude

Comment: It doesn't like all arguments? Was the error `I hate the arguments`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you copy paste the code? You have typo using ls instead of lt (min_longitude__ls)

Comment: Found the problem... Thank you!